# Django Bootstrap Dropdown Menu Empty

Tags: html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I want to extract a list of objects and put them in a drop down menu. I already did that and it worked, but not on a dropdown menu, maybe the problem is in my HTML I don't know.
Here is my html part:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Choisissez une structure existante<span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        {% for s in structures %}
        <li>{{ s.name }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

I already did this to display structures in a table in another html template and it worked: here is the working code:

```
<tbody>
{% for structure in structures %}
   <tr>
      <td><center>{{ structure.name }}</center></td>
      <td><center>{{ structure.created_at }}</center></td>
      <td><center>{{ structure.updated_at }}</center></td>
      <td><center>{{ structure.file }}</center></td>
      <td>
        <a href="/edit/{{ structure.id }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Modifier</a>
        <a href="/delete/{{ structure.id }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Supprimer</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

Thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your html with a dropdown around.

```
<li class="dropdown">
   <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Structures</a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       {% for s in structures %}
           <li><a href="#">{{ s.id }}</a></li>
       {% endfor %}
   </ul>
</li>
```

There is a js requirement as well in bootstrap assuming you have included that.

Comment: I did all that and still doesn't give me any structure: I changed the code (you can check out my edit). Now It shows the drop down list but it's empty.